# Как убрать скобки при выводе, где только одно число?

Tags: python, словари

```
favourite_numbers = {
    'mom': [12, 7, 53, 275, 2, 29, 15],
    'dad': [77, 33, 65, 50],
    'granny': [22],
    'anastasia': [44],
    }
for name, values in favourite_numbers.items():
    if len(values) == 1:
        values = str(values)
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite number is {''.join(values)}")
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite numbers are:")
        for number in values:
            print(number)
```

Вывод:
...
Granny's favourite number is [22]
Anastasia's favourite number is [44]

Comment: Можно просто вывести значение элемента массива `values[0]` - это первый элемент массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выводить можно всё одинаково, а изменить только текст:

```
for name, values in favourite_numbers.items():
    if len(values) == 1:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite number is: ")
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite numbers are: ")
    for number in values:
        print(number)
```

Или даже так

```
for name, values in favourite_numbers.items():
    if len(values) == 1:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite number is: ")
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}'s favourite numbers are: ")
    print(*values) # "распаковывает" список, т.е. выводит каждый элемент
```